# Autocomplete not working on cloned divs

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have included the automcomplete JS as well as the data for the autocomplete

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>

$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#taskform").clone().appendTo("#taskform");
});

$(function(){
  var staffnames = [
    { value: 'Stephen', data: 's1' },
    { value: 'Klay', data: 's2' },
    { value: 'Draymond', data: 's3' },
    { value: 'Andre', data: 's4' },
    { value: 'Harrison', data: 's5' },
    { value: 'LeBron', data: 's6' },
  ];

  $('#staffsearch').autocomplete({
    lookup: staffnames,
  });
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form>
  <div id="taskform">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm font11" placeholder="Staff" name="staff" id="staffsearch" value="">
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-info input-sm font11 addanother" onlick="duplicate()" id="button" value="Add Another Staff">
</form>
```

The autocomplete works initially. But when I clone it, the cloned div/input's autocomplete does not work, although the original's autocomplete still works.

Probably have to do with the same ID for both the original and cloned input? Not sure how I work around it though.

Any help is very much appreciated.

B

Comment: Firstly you need to change the `id` to a class as you are duplicating the `id` multiple times, which is invalid. Secondly, are you intentionally nesting the cloned `#taskform` elements? It seems a little odd. I think you may want to insert them before the input instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have a few input fields inside the id taskform though. also, if I change the ID to a class, how do I go about referencing the original and the cloned inputs? thanks

Comment: @Pete when I type on the cloned, the autocomplete is appearing on the original input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but do you want something like that :

https://jsfiddle.net/ye1uzwmg/1/

```
var staffnames = [{
    value: 'Stephen',
    data: 's1'
  }, {
    value: 'Klay',
    data: 's2'
  }, {
    value: 'Draymond',
    data: 's3'
  }, {
    value: 'Andre',
    data: 's4'
  }, {
    value: 'Harrison',
    data: 's5'
  }, {
    value: 'LeBron',
    data: 's6'
  }, ];

$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#taskform").find("input[type='text']").last().clone().val('').appendTo("#taskform").autocomplete({
    source: staffnames,
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.staffauto').autocomplete({
    source: staffnames,
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks like what I needed based on the jsfiddle. I would try it out. Can the clone have blank value on initial load?

Comment: ah, one issue I see is when I do have multiple input fields to be cloned (which is what I intend to do)

Comment: looks like it doubles up the input field, like when there are already four and the clone button is clicked, the result would be 8 input fields.  Also, what I mean is there will be 2 initial input fields to be cloned, both autocomplete with different data